# Refund email with image attachment

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm making an Api view for a Refund so when the form is filled an email get sent to the admin email with some data including an image as an attachment. I was testing my code that is included below and i am getting an error that `Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/skjema/ Exception Value: 'Refund' object has no attribute 'splitlines'` and when i removed the `r` from the ms on EmailMessage and replaced it with a string i got the email with the image and the string which probably means i have something right in my code.
If someone can help me fixing the splitlines problem that would be realy appreciated.

models.py

```
from datetime import datetime

class Refund(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = "Refund")
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date = models.DateField()
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    contact_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

from .models import Refund


class Refund(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]


    def post(self, request, format=None):

        data = self.request.data

        r = Refund(name= request.POST['name'],email=request.POST['email'],address=request.POST['address'], date=request.POST['date'],message =request.POST['message'],amount =request.POST['amount'],image = request.FILES['image'])
        msg = EmailMessage('Refund',r ,'user@gmail.com',['admin@gmail.com'],headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'})
        msg.content_subtype = "html"

        mime_image = MIMEImage(r.image.read(),_subtype=str(r.image.name)[-1])
        mime_image.add_header('Content-ID', '<image>')
        msg.attach(mime_image)
        print('mime image',mime_image)
        msg.send()
        return Response({'success': 'Sent'})
```

Comment: Don't name your view `Refund`. It overrides the reference to the `Refund` model.

Comment: oh ok thanks i'll change it, but i don't think that would solve the problem, right??

Comment: Furthermore what is `r` supposed to do? The second parameter is supposed to contain the *body* of the email, not a `Refund` object.

Comment: no, since it makes no sense to use a `Refund` object when constructing the email.

Comment: i was thinking the `r` objects supose to be the body since i want to send the form that user filled. so the email body would be the name, email, addres, date, message and amount

Comment: then you will need to generate a string from that `Refund` object that generates the body of the email.

Comment: do u have an idea how to do that. because the image is also part of the data in `r`

Comment: just construct a HTML email with `<img src="hostname.com/path/to/image.jpg">`.

Comment: sorry for the disturb, but how would i know the image name

Comment: Since you did not save the `Refund` object to the database, there simply is no such file. But if it is saved, then you wan work with `r.image.url`.